# I want to find index of particular array of name dynamically by using java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My sample code

```
<div class="my_class_1">
    <input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="2" />
</div>
<div class="my_class_2">
    <input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="3" />
    <input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="4" />
</div>

<div class="my_class_3">
    <input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="5" />
    <input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="6" />
</div>
```

Here 
textbox with name_1 will get added dynamically inside any div my_class_1/ my_class_2 / my_class_3
while adding new input type i wanted to fetch previous value and added to new textbox
For ex
If i'm adding new textbox for div class my_class_1
the new textbox value should be 2
like this

```
<input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="2" />
```

when i'm adding new textbox for div class my_class_2
the new textbox value should be 4
like this

```
<input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="4" />
```

I tried some methds in javascript

```
<script>
let lastElement = document.getElementsByName("name_1[]");
let leng1 = lastElement.length;
lastValue = (typeof lastElement[lastElement-1] == 'undefined') ?  0 : lastElement[lastElement - 1].value;
</script>
```

This always returning me the last value

Can anyone help me on this 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why you are not saving your desired value on any kind of hidden input field then try to get it by js

Comment: yes,i can keep, but even user has provision to change value of textbox and adding one more new textbox, this time i need to refresh my hidden filed for last user updated value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) you can select a single element with CSS selectors. So what you could do is select the container in which the input is that you want to select and use the `:last-of-type` pseudo selector to select the last input that has the criteria you are searching for. This allows to always select the last input in the correct position.

```js
let lastElement = document.querySelector('.my_class_2 input[name="name_1[]"]:last-of-type');
let lastValue = lastElement.value;
console.log(lastElement, lastValue);
```

```html
<div class="my_class_1">
    <input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="2" />
</div>
<div class="my_class_2">
    <input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="3" />
    <input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="4" />
</div>

<div class="my_class_3">
    <input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="5" />
    <input type="text" name="name_1[]" value="6" />
</div>
```